# Get data from a table html with click

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternoon, I'm a beginner, I'm having trouble getting information from a table that consumes data from an api.

```
    index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="apendeOnClick()">
    <table id="tablerow">
        <caption>Alien football stars</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>DATA</th>
                <th>TELEFONE</th>
                <th>RAMAL</th>
                <th>DESCRIÇÃO</th>
                <th>ACÕES</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table_body">
                   
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is this, it feeds the table normally, but I would like when the person clicks on the row button to display the information in the alert.

```
main.js
fetch("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/lfnoleto/api-fake/contact").then((data) => {
    return data.json()
}).then((Objectdata) => {
    //console.log(Objectdata[0].data)
    let tabelaData = ""
  

    Objectdata.map((values)=>{
       
        tabelaData += `<tr>
            <td>${values.data}</td>
            <td>${values.tefone}</td>
            <td>${values.ramal}</td>
            <td>${values.descricao}</td>
            <td><button id="butao" class="btn btn-success" ><i class="fa fa-phone"></button></td>
        </tr>`
        
    })

    document.getElementById("table_body").innerHTML = tabelaData
    innerHTML = tabelaData

    
})

function apendeOnClick(){

    const table = document.getElementById("tablerow")
    console.log(table)
    if (table) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
          table.rows[i].childNodes[5].childNodes[1].onclick = function() {
            tableText(this);
          };
        }
    }
}

function tableText(tableRow) {
    let telefone = tableRow.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
    let ramal = tableRow.childNodes[2].innerHTML;
    let obj = {'telefone': telefone, 'ramal': ramal};
    console.log(obj);
  }
```

I hope that when the person clicks on the telephone icon, he displays the extension and telephone information

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use data attribute to store extension info or other information.

```
<button id="butao" data-extension="123" class="btn btn-success" >
```

in javascript :

```
const button = document.querySelector('button'); 

button.dataset.extention // "123"
```

a good references:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes